# += operator in C++ to add Autors to list

Tags: c++, operators, shared-ptr

I was wondering how I can items to a list by using the += operator in c++;

In my main I have something like this:

```
  Bibliography herbspubs("Herb Sutter");
  std::shared_ptr<Paper> king = std::make_shared<Paper>("The return of the King", 2009, "Dr. Dobbs journal", 1.56f);
  king->addAuthor(std::make_shared<std::string>("Joe Walsh"));
```

But the addAuthor function I want to change to a += operator to add authors. How is this possible? This so that I can add an author to any publication. My publication class is connected with :

- Book
- Papper
- Letter
- Conference

My publication.h looks like:

```
#ifndef PUBLICATIONS_H
#define PUBLICATIONS_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> otherAuthors;
class Publications
  {
  public:
    explicit Publications(std::string orderTitle, int aYear, std::string aPublisher);

  private:

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> otherAuthors;
  };


std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> operator +=(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> otherAuthors,const std::shared_ptr<std::string> newAuthor);

#endif // PUBLICATIONS_H
```

Publication.cpp

```
void Publications::addAuthor(const std::shared_ptr<std::string> newAuthor)
{
    otherAuthors+=newAuthor;
    //otherAuthors.push_back(newAuthor);

}

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> operator +=(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> otherAuthors,const std::shared_ptr<std::string> newAuthor){
    otherAuthors.push_back(newAuthor);
    return otherAuthors;
}
```

Doesn't trow an error but it only add's the last author. How can I implement that it keeps all the Authors in otherAuthors?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tk49fh2.aspx

Comment: You're passing and returning the vector by value so only copies will be affected. Change to using references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use references because you are passing the vector as a copy and it does not affect on its contents.
Try like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> operator +=(std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> &otherAuthors,const std::shared_ptr<std::string> newAuthor){
    otherAuthors.push_back(newAuthor);
    return otherAuthors;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem with your implementation:**

If you want your operator+= to provide similar behaviour than the build-in operator, you have to adopt a similar signature:  you have to operate on a reference and return that reference:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> & operator+= (std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::string>> & otherAuthors, const std::shared_ptr<std::string> newAuthor) {
    otherAuthors.push_back(newAuthor);
    return otherAuthors;
}
```

See also the standard, section 13.6/18.  You may by the way be interested in these useful [rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x88tzx0.aspx) and [guidelines for operator overloading](http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html).

With your signature, you first make a copy of the vector to construct the argument,  then you will change this copy and not the original.  Then you'll return another copy of the changed vector which is not the normal behaviour of a compound assignment.

**Other problems with your approach:**

I think your approach is dangerous, as it overloads `+=` not only for authors in an author list, but for any vector of shared pointers to strings.

May be it is your intention.  But if not, this can also have unexpected side effects and quickly go out of control.

Think also about consistency of operators.  For built-in operators one would expect `a += b` to provide the same results than `a = a + b` or  a = b + a (commutativity of addition).  Of course you're not obliged to respect this meaning, but if the behaviour of your overloaded operator is very different from this principle, you should ask yourself whether it's really such a great idea.  After all, it's [only some syntactic sugar](http://www.drbio.cornell.edu/pl47/programming/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-one-html/Chapter12.html).